# How can I get rid of the section that the bibliography environment creates?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, bibliographies

I am working on a short presentation using `beamer`. As the presentation is fairly short (less than 15 slides), I decided not to set sections within the presentation.

The problem I am having is that, when I introduce a bibliography at the end of the presentation using BibTeX, it creates a section, named "References". I do not know how I can get rid of it, so as to not create a section bar at the bottom of the presentation using the `Warsaw` theme.

Here is a MWE of my presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[round, comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\justifying
\let\Tiny \tiny

\title{Presentation}
\author{Author's Name}
\institute{University}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Other stuff}
    Here are two cites: \cite{Greenberg2008} and \cite{Robert2004}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{thebibliography}{2}
        \bibitem[Greenberg, 2008]{Greenberg2008} Greenberg, E. (2008).
        \newblock {\em {Introduction to Bayesian Econometrics}}.
        \newblock Cambridge University Press.
        \bibitem[Robert and Casella, 2004]{Robert2004} Robert, C.~P. and Casella, G. (2004).
        \newblock {\em {Monte Carlo Statistical Methods}}. \newblock Springer-Verlag.
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy enough to completely remove the use of `\section`s in your presentation by adding

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{}
```

to your preamble. Since `thebibliography` issues a `\section*{References}`, it'll merely gobble the `*` and `{References}`.

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy-to-use interface for capturing arguments of different types (include starred-versions). If you don't want to use `xparse`, then you can add

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar\sectiongobble\sectiongobble}
\newcommand{\sectiongobble}[2][]{}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble, which acts in the same way.

Comment: I know that the `\section*` command is used in `thebibliography` for standard classes, but I did not find in the beamer bunch of files. It works, but I don't understand why ;-)

Comment: A difficult choice. The first solution is more elegant, but the second allows you to `gobble`!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes. [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) defines `thebibliography` as purely a list (see the definition in [`beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty)). It's [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) (and possibly other reference packages) that update `thebibliography` to insert a `\section*{..}`.

Comment: @Werner: Oh damn, I forgot the `natbib` package ;-) Learned something again! Thanks